# Javascript: Prepend with HTML code including img src and href's

Tags: jquery, html, image, prepend, slicknav

Trying to add some prepend code to a SlickNav menu and while basic HTML works, once I add things like img's and href's, the code fails. I know this is incorrect, but I'm wondering what would work here:

```
jQuery('.slicknav_menu').prepend('<div class=\"logo\"><a href=\"https://example.com/\" rel=\"home\"><img src=\"https://example.com/images/logo-round.svg\" alt=\"My Site\" onerror=\"this.onerror=null; this.src='https://example.com/images/logo-round.png'\"></a></div>');
```

I know this will work:

```
jQuery('.slicknav_menu').prepend('<div class=\"logo\">LOGO</div>');
```

But the other is more advanced. So how can I make that work so it displays the svg (or png) image?

Comment: look at the syntax highlighting... you are escaping the wrong quotes and not escaping the single quotes that need escaping

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found the code that seems to work. This displays everything and the link is correct:

```
jQuery('.slicknav_menu').prepend(\"<div class=\\\"site-title\\\"><a href=\\\"https://thecleverroot.com/\\\" rel=\\\"home\\\"><img src=\\\"https://thecleverroot.com/wp-content/themes/clever-root/images/logo.svg\\\" alt=\\\"The Clever Root\\\" onerror=\'this.onerror=null; this.src=\\\"https://thecleverroot.com/themes/clever-root/images/logo-round.png\\\"\'></a></div>\");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way would be

```
jQuery('.slicknav_menu').prepend('<div class="logo"><a href="https://example.com/" rel="home"><img src="https://example.com/images/logo-round.svg" alt="My Site" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=\'https://example.com/images/logo-round.png\'"></a></div>');
```

If you start with the simple quote, then you need to escape the simple quote.

for example:

```
$('.slicknav_menu').prepend('<div class="logo" id=\'id_exemple\'>Teste</div>');
```

Comment: Your method doesn't work. I get syntax errors trying the method above. The double quotes are the issue. And you need them for a href and img src attributes.

Comment: I think the problem is I'm making a direct call to https://example.com/ and it's those slashes that are causing things to get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo the comment left by @charlietfl, syntax highlighters are a good friend.  Always hard to do manually, but just be sure to keep track of single quote and double quote escaping.